# chrome extension using d3

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, d3.js

I am currently writing a Chrome extension (I'm kind of new into that) and want to use d3 for visualizing some stuff on a website. I am using a background.js script for manipulating the site by clicking on the extension icon.

background.js:

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
  chrome.tabs.executeScript( {file: "reviews.js" });
});
```

so this will redirect me to my review.js where I've got several functions:

```
var w = window.innerWidth - 50;
var h = 50;

var setupDependencies = function() {
  var head = document.getElementsByTagName("head");
  script = document.createElement("script");
  script.src = "http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js";
  script.charset = "utf-8";
  head[0].appendChild(script);
}

setupDependencies();

var smartReviewSVG = d3.select(".smartReviews")
                       .append("svg")
                       .attr("width", w)
                       .attr("height", h+10);
```

but the problem I guess is just that d3 is just available after the script has done one complete run. So now my question:

How can I use d3 within this script?

Answer (score 3):

Okay so in the End I found a solution by myself:
So my Background Script is loading the whole d3 lib for me like this:

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
  chrome.tabs.executeScript( {file: "d3/d3.min.js"});
  chrome.tabs.executeScript( {file: "reviews.js" });
});
```

Thats it.

Answer (score 0):

You can run the rest of the code *after* the `d3` script loads:

```
function runD3() {
    var smartReviewSVG = d3.select(".smartReviews")
                       .append("svg")
                       .attr("width", w)
                       .attr("height", h+10);
}

var setupDependencies = function() {
  var head = document.getElementsByTagName("head");
  var script = document.createElement("script");
  script.onload = runD3;
  script.onerror = function () { alert('Failed to load D3.') };
  script.src = "http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js";
  script.charset = "utf-8";
  head[0].appendChild(script);
}

setupDependencies();
```

*Note:* Chrome extensions may have a better way of dealing with delayed loading of scripts though; I do not have any experience in that area.